# Called upon to +verb

Tags: grammar, word-choice

Is the following sentence correct? The part after 'called upon' sounds a bit strange to me.

'SIRE (a company) calls upon to keep hands off our social workers, so this video must be aimed at individuals who use violence against the people that are always ready to help us.'

Comment: So, it is fine to use 'call upon' without adding the person(s) who are called upon?

Comment: Apologies for my error. No. SIRE must call upon someone, e.g. the public.

Comment: Oh, but what can I use instead of 'calls upon' here?

Comment: SIRE calls upon the public to keep **their** (or its) hands off our social workers

Comment: Can you also say: SIRE makes a call to keep hands off social workers, so...

Answer (score 1):

Used as in your sentence, the phrasal verb *to call upon*,  meaning to invite or ask somebody to do something, is followed by an object. That is to say, it is a transitive phrasal verb. You call upon [someone] to [do something].

> call upon phrasal verb
>   call on/upon somebody (formal) ​
>
> to formally invite or ask somebody to speak, etc.
>   *I now call upon the chairman to address the meeting.*

[Call upon (Oxford Learner's Dictionaries)](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/call-upon)